# How to Redirect only if form is not empty , JavaScript Validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Right now even if input fields are empty , if submit button is pressed it shows alert"message": and then redirects to window.location="URL"

What I m looking for is it only shows done alert and redirects if input fields are filled

```html
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter name here">

            <input type="number" placeholder="enter number here">

            <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="submit">
        </form>

    </center>
</body>
  
<script type="text/javascript">

    const submitit = document.getElementById('submitbutton');

    submitit.addEventListener("click",function(){
        alert("Done, Meanwhile check our website");
        window.location="https://www.google.com";   
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<form>
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="enter name here">

  <input id="number" type="number" placeholder="enter number here">

  <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="submit">
</form>
```

and JavaScript:

```js
const submitit = document.getElementById('submitbutton');

submitit.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // prevent form from being submitted
  e.preventDefault();

  alert("Done, Meanwhile check our website");

  const name = document.getElementById('name');
  const number = document.getElementById('number');

  if (name.value !== '' && number.value !== '') {
    window.location = "https://www.google.com"; 
  }  
});
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/vyspiansky/v7yjwL6x/

Comment: Thanks man this worked , I just modified it a bit by adding ```` else { alert ("error "); }```` problem is I have ```` form action ="somewhere.php"```` and by adding that javascript code the form data isn't being sent to PHP , but if I intentionally ruin the code by adding extra semicolons or brackets , that stops javascript to work .. then the data is being sent to Php , Can you figure out the solution for this please ?

Comment: Does it solve your problem? https://jsfiddle.net/vyspiansky/wzv39q6a/